# python の async await の使い方：'await' outside function

Tags: python

async await をつかった並列処理の勉強中なのですが

```
import time

async def sleep_echo(x):
  print('start' + x)
  time.sleep(10)
  print('end ' + x)
  return x

result1 = await sleep_echo('1')
result2 = await sleep_echo('2')
print(result1)
print(result2)
```

これで

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

がでるんですがなぜでしょうか

ロジックミスならともかく
いろいろな記事を見ても await をメソッド前につけるだけなのに
文法エラーになる理由がよくわかりません

outside function っていうから

```
def main():
  result1 = await sleep_echo('1')
  result2 = await sleep_echo('2')
  print(result1)
  print(result2)

main()
```

と書いても同じです

async await を取り除けば動くことは確認しました
await がかける位置に何か条件があるんでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [SyntaxError: 'await' outside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461052/) 引用: "await should always be inside an async function."

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Pythonのasyncioで非同期にリクエストを飛ばす](https://www.sambaiz.net/article/162/), [How to run asynchronous web requests in parallel with Python 3.5 (without aiohttp)](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-asynchronous-web-requests-in-parallel-with-python-3-5-without-aiohttp-264dc0f8546), [pythonで複数のhttp requestを同時に投げる方法(requests)について](https://pod.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/09/22/215030)

Comment: @chico [新しい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62148/19110)の方でも触れられていますが、追記部分はタイトルに書かれている元々の質問内容から離れているので、その部分はこの質問からは削除して新しい質問として投稿されるのが良さそうです。

Comment: 具体的にどの追記部分が重複してますか？　ききたい本命はこちらの追記部分でHTTPに特化した処理が知りたいわけではないのです。ただ汎用的な並列化コードの回答が来ないので仕方なくHTTPのコードであちこちにprintはさんで挙動を理解しようかと思ってたところで謎の現象に遭遇したので別質問として投稿した感じです。

Comment: 「await がかける位置に何か条件があるんでしょうか？」より下に書かれていることは丸々削除して新しい質問にするのが良いと思っています。そもそも[最初の方の版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/62081/3)では「awaitを関数の外に書いたらエラーが出る。何故？」というご質問であり、それに対して回答が投稿されました。しかしその後「並列化するには？」という疑問点がつけたされ、ご質問の方向が変わりました。このように質問の内容が変わってしまうと、回答の良し悪しが変わってしまい投票の意味が薄くなったり、折角書いた回答を書きなおさないといけなくなったりして大変です。このためひとつの質問で聞くことはひとつにし、疑問点がひとつ解決するたびに新しい質問をするのをオススメしています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` は `async` で宣言された関数の中でのみ使えます。

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression

> It is a SyntaxError to use await outside of an async def function (like it is a SyntaxError to use yield outside of def function).

並列処理という事なので、多分↓のようなコードになるのかな。

```
import asyncio


async def sleep_echo(x):
    print('start' + x)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('end ' + x)
    return x


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = asyncio.gather(
    sleep_echo('1'),
    sleep_echo('2'),
)

results = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
print(results)
```

---

### 追記: asyncを使ったhttpリクエストの並列化

`aiohttp` を使うのが手っ取り早いと思います。

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print(await response.text())


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(
            fetch(session, 'https://www.rakuten.co.jp/'),
            fetch(session, 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/'),
        )

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

#### 追記: fork-exec-waitによるマルチプロセス(unix限定)

```
import os
import sys
import time

def count(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    count(10)
    os._exit(0)
else:
    count(10)

child_pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)

print("child_pid = %d, status= %d" % (child_pid, status))
```

もちろんこれは `multiprocessing` モジュールで以下のように書けます。

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def count(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

for num in range(2):
    mp.Process(target=count, args=(10,)).start()
```

Comment: async の中にしか書けないんですね…　あと asyncio.sleep がよくわかってないので追記しました

Comment: asyncとmultiprocessとthreadがごっちゃになっちゃってるんじゃないかと思います。asyncはシングルスレッドの中でイベントを待ち受る永久ループがひとつぐるぐる常にブン回ってるイメージです。time.sleep はPythonドキュメントにあるようにスレッドを止めてしまうので、asyncなコードで使うとイベントループが止まってしまうでしょう。マルチスレッド/マルチプロセスならtime.sleepで結構です。 `requests.get` のようなHTTPリクエストの並列化をasyncでやるなら、 aiohttp モジュールなんかを見るといいかもしれません。

Comment: asyncを使ったhttpリクエストの並列化について追記しました。

Comment: fork-exec-wait について追記しました。必要だったのはasyncでなくてマルチプロセスの方だったってことかしら。

Comment: せっかくいろいろ回答いただいたんですが後半の質問は消した方がいいといわれたので消してしまいました。申し訳ありません

Comment: 私も至らないところがありうまく回答できていなかったかもしれません。申し訳ない。とはいえ質問は小分けになっていると後から検索した人にとって便利だと思います。どうか気を悪くされないでください。